# How to use C to solve Two Sum correctly?

Tags: c, interview-questions

**Two Sum Problem:**

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

```
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].
```

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target){
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++){
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                a[0] = i;
                a[1] = j;
                return a;
            }
        }
    }
} /* Error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type] */
```

Comment: Are you asking about the error? (your title suggest the same). The error here is quite straight forward: If `nums` simply do not contain a combination that adds to `target`, then the method lacks a return statement. You could e.g. return `-1` twice if no combination is found. However, this is not on topic for CodeReview.SE since this code currently does not work. StackOverflow would be the place to post this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done this:

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
#define INVALID (-1)
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target)
{
    int *result = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    memset (result, INVALID, sizeof(int) * 2);
    for(int left = 0; left < numsSize && result[0] == INVALID; left++)
    {
        for(int right = left+ 1; right < numsSize && result[0] == INVALID; right++)
        {
            if (nums[left] + nums[right] == target)
            {
                result[0] = left;
                result[1] = right;
                /* A return statement here instead of the overhead of the 
                   second check in the for loop conditions may be a good
                   idea, it depends if the driving factor is performance
                   or maintainability */
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Since this is an interview question and you are showing what a shining star you are you might want to consider the following points:

- Its best to avoid multiple return points if you can, but there is
  going to be a performance hit.  By adding the comment I think I have
  shown that I have identified that issue and, right or wrong, made a
  decision and explained why.
- Setting the results as early as possible may be a waste of a few
  processor cycles but it will help when the code goes wrong, you know
  you are going to have random values sneaking out, imagine what would
  happen if `results[0] = 5;`
- Using single letter variables means you have to right more
  comments/documents to explain your code.  This is an interview
  question, you don't want to submit a 20 page document detailing what
  a, i, j mean and their range of values do you.  (left and right are
  not very descriptive names, but they are better than i and j).

All I did was add one line and polish the turd a bit, which is much easier when I'm not being interviewed, good luck !

Comment: @pacmaninbw - Thanks, copy and paste error, now fixed.